# reading input from file until specific word is read

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

i am writing a java program to read a file and print output to another string variable.which is working perfectly as intended using is code.

```
{
String key = "";
FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/raju/Desktop/input.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
String line = reader.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    key += line;
    line = reader.readLine();
}

System.out.println(key); //this prints contents of .txt file
}
```

this prints whole text in the file.But i want to only print the lines till word END is encountered in file.

example: if input.txt file contains following text : this test file END extra in

it should print only :
this test file

Comment: did you also consider using a if + break construct in the while loop?

Comment: `if (line.contains("END"))`

Comment: You should also use a `StringBuilder` to assemble your output if you care a bit about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple indexOf to see where it is and if it exists in the line. If the instance is found one option would be using substring to cut off everything up until the index of the keyword. For a bit more control though try using java regular expressions.

```
String key = "";
FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/raju/Desktop/input.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
String line = reader.readLine();

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && line.indexOf("Keyword to look for") == -1)
    key += line;


System.out.println(key);
```

Comment: this is not giving any output

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it needs to be any more complicated than this:

```
BufferedReader re = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true) {
        String str = re.readLine();
        if (str.equals("exit")) break;

     // whatever other code.

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your logic to check if the line contains "END".

If END not found in a line, add the line to key stringin your program

If yes, split that line into word array, read the line till you encounter the word "END" and append it to your key string. Consider using Stringbuilder for key.

```
   while (line != null) {

        line = reader.readLine();
        if(!line.contains("END")){
            key += line;
        }else{

            //Note that you can use split logic like below, or use java substring
            String[] words = line.split("");
            for(String s : words){
                if(s.equals("END")){
                    return key;
                }
                key += s;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in many ways. one of them is using `indexOf` method to specify the start index of "END" in input and then using `subString` method.

for more information, read documentation of `String` calss. [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score -1):

This will work for your issue.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String key = "";

    FileReader file = new FileReader("/home/halil/khalil.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        key += line;
        line = reader.readLine();
    } String output = "";
    if(key.contains("END")) {
        output = key.split("END")[0];
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```